# Angular 2: Route data resolution in child component

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-components

I have a component which is loaded(routed) on successful data resolution using resolvers at the router level. The data retrieved from the server is to be passed to the child components. The data is resolved and accordingly passed but child component throws an error of

> trying to access from undefined

.

Scenario:

Parent Component HTML:

```
 <parent>
   <child [_data]="dataFromResolver"></child>
 </parent>
```

Parent Component.ts

```
export class Parent implements OnInit {

    dataFromResolver: any;

    constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute) {
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.route.data.forEach((data: any) => {
          this.dataFromResolver = data;
        });
    }
}
```

Resolver Service:

```
resolve(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot): Observable<boolean | any> {
    return this.parentService.getData().map(output => {
        if (output) {
            return output;
        } else {
            this.router.navigate(['/login']);
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

Child Compnent.ts

```
@Input() _data(value: any) {
        this.data = value;
    }


    data: any;
```

Child Component HTML

```
<p>{{data.name}}</p>
```

Route has also been configured accordingly and I can see data coming in network tab of browser tools.

Please let me know if any I am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error I have missed `set` after `@Input()`. A blunder mistake.